# Vue Mount to ID of Table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding

I'm building a matrix of checkboxes presented in a table. I'm using Vue3.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

I want to bind the Checked property of each to a boolean, defined like this:

```
const app = Vue.createApp
            ({
                data() {
                    return {
                        Property1: false,
                        Property2: false,
                        Property3: false,
                        Property4: false,
                        Property5: false,
                        Property6: false
                        // etcetera...
                    }
                }
            })
      
            var App = app.mount('#main')
```

'main' is the ID of an html table.

When I run it, app.mount() fails and App is null. The error message I see is pretty long, but starts out like this:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element':
> 'left;' is not a valid attribute name.

The error is in here:

> https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js:10188:12

The table has a fair amount of CSS attached, including a 'margin-left' setting. I'm wondering if that was is throwing the error. This is start of the table definition:

```
<table id="main" style="margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px" width="410px">
```

Each table row and cell has CSS as well.

I built a simple proof-of-concept, with just 2 checkboxes in a Div, and that worked. So, I'm at a loss as to what to try next. Thanks for any ideas.